# Flask SQLAlchemy Query

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I have created a Flask project using Miguel Grinbergs' excellent tutorials. I am adapting the example code to make my own site.

I have two tables in my db. Drivers and Teams. I have created a One-to-Many relationship in models.py and I want to output a list of drivers and the team they belong to. I have included routes.py and the html file that will display the results.

The query in routes.py works fine if I specify one driver within the query, but when I try Drivers.query.all(), it does not return any data on the web page.

**NOTE** = I have ran the

```
Drivers.query.all()
```

within a Python Shell and I get the correct response, it is only when I try to implement the solution on the web page that I experience the problem.

output from Python Shell

```
>>> details = Driver.query.all()
>>> details
[<Driver Lewis Hamilton>, <Driver Kimi Raikkonen>, <Driver Max Verstappen>]
>>> for d in details:
...     print(d.driverName, d.driverTeam)
... 
Lewis Hamilton Mercedes
Kimi Raikkonen Ferrari
Max Verstappen Red Bull
>>>
```

models.py

```
class Team(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    teamName = db.Column(db.String(64))
    teamDriver = db.relationship('Driver', backref='driverTeam', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.teamName)


class Driver(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    driverName = db.Column(db.String(64))
    team_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('team.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Driver {}>'.format(self.driverName)
```

routes.py

```
@app.route('/driverDetails', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def driverDetails():
    ## Output works fine with one driver specified in query
    # details = Driver.query.filter_by(driverName='Kimi Raikkonen').first()

    ## No data is output when using query below
    details = Driver.query.all()
    return render_template('driverDetails.html',  title='Driver Details', details=details)
```

driverDetails.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Driver Details</h1>
    <!-- Output works correctly for one driver as specified in query on routes.py
    <div><p>{{ details.driverName }} is in: <b>{{ details.driverTeam }}</b></p></div>
    -->

    <!-- However, when trying to iterate over whole list of drivers, output shows 
    the text "drives for:". But there is no data being populated from the db
    -->
    {% for d in details %}
    <div><p>{{ details.driverName }} drives for: {{ details.driverTeam }}</p></div>
    {% endfor %}
   {% endblock %}
```

I would appreciate any advice on where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code is basically correct, you just need to actually use the object you are binding to `d`:

```
{% for d in details %}
<div><p>{{ d.driverName }} drives for: {{ d.driverTeam }}</p></div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Ah brilliant! Many thanks joppich! Can't believe I didn't notice that myself!